# Splitting XML into self-contained chunks

Tags: rust

I am parsing a huge XML file (>100 GB) using quick-xml in rust from a `BufReader`.

I would like to fan out the parsing into multiple threads. Is there a fast XML splitter that splits the `BufReader` input into self-contained XML chunks which I can then parse individually using quick-xml?

Comment: How would this even work? You can't just seek to a random file and expect to start parsing the XML properly.

Comment: I thought about doing a fast scan of xml-element boundaries, and fan out those chunks to different threads that do the actual decoding.

Comment: In general, such chunks could not be assumed to be valid in any way because of PIs and namespace declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if such crate exists and if it did, how well it would fit to your needs, but if you decide to do it on your own and you know the structure of your file, I would guess you most probably have many entities like this:

```
<root>
    <entity>
        ...
    </entity>
    <entity>
        ...
    </entity>
    <entity>
        ...
    </entity>
    ...
<root>
```

So if each `entity` is big/complex enough, you should benefit from splitting the string so that each string part corresponds to one `"<entity> ... </entity>"` string (slice). You could do that splitting on the fly, within a single iteration. You could use a pool of worker threads that parse each of those string parts in parallel and at the end combine them in the desired data structure, let's say `Vec<Entity>`.

Of course, you should also consider what you can put in RAM if you are dealing with such huge XML files.

That suggested approach can offer *some* performance boost and is relatively simple. It is possible to optimize it further, of course, but it's hard to come up with the most optimal solution without knowing the specifics of your task.

Also, be sure all of that is really worth it. Measure the time it takes to read the file from the IO, as often times that would actually be the bottleneck. Make sure you test with big files, otherwise the system's IO cache might mislead you your IO read speed is higher than it really is.

Comment: Except you can't be certain that a found `</entity>` pairs with a previously found `<entity>` without parsing the file...

Comment: @eggyal Why? If you have expect nested entities like `<entity>...<entity>...</entity>...</entity>`, you can simply use a counter. Also, I assume the file is a *valid* XML file w/o too complicated cases of namespaces, etc. Are there any other cases that you have in mind?

Comment: I think the bigger issue is we don't know enough about the problem to determine the end goal and when we no longer need a part in memory. I assume this may need to run on a device with less memory than the file size. We can keep reading until we find the closing tag for an element we are searching for. If we exceed some buffer limit without finding a closing tag, we switch to looking for the closing tag of the next nested xml instead until we either find a chunk small enough to parse and remove from the buffer or exceed memory limits and exit. But this may require a lot of custom handling.

Comment: @at54321: Not only might `<entity>` tags be nested, but one `<entity>` might also be in a different namespace to another `<entity>` or `</entity>`.  Perhaps you can guarantee that such things will *never* be the case with your input file, but then strictly speaking we're not talking about XML generally but rather some restricted subset thereof.